# Seeking an example of Schwartz function $f$ such that $ \int_{\bf R}\left|\frac{f(x-y)}{y}\right|\ dy=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, harmonic-analysis

In the introduction section of [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) in Grafakos's *[Classical Fourier Analysis](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9781441918550)* (3rd) (Section 5.1.1), it is said that

> for Schwartz functions $f$, the integral 
>   $$
> \int_{\bf R}\frac{f(x-y)}{y}\ dy\tag{1}
> $$
>   may not converge absolutely for any real number $x$.

This motivates the use of principal value integrals:
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{|y|\geq\epsilon}\frac{f(x-y)}{y}\ dy.
$$

**Question:** Could anyone give an example such that (1) does not converge absolutely?

Comment: @MarkViola: Thanks for your comment. While I know the definition of Schwartz functions, I don't have a bag of examples at hand, can you give one?

Comment: The issue is the singularity at $y=0$.

Comment: @MarkViola I don't think $O(1)$ is what you mean, because every Schwartz function satisfies that. Also note it was to hold for all $x.$

Comment: Any positive Schwartz function will do, for example $f(y) = e^{-y^2}.$

Comment: @zhw.  Please disregard the previous comment.

Comment: The issue is that $\int_{|y|<\epsilon} \frac{1}{|y|} dy = \infty$ for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. In particular if $f$ is Schwartz and non-zero (see zhw.'s answer/comments) at $x$, then it follows $|f(z)|>c>0$ on some $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $x$, so that 
$$ \int_{\mathbb R}\frac{|f(x-y)|}{|y|} dy ≥ c\int_{|y|<\epsilon } \frac{1}{|y|}dy = \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

If the Schwartz function $f$ is $0$ at $x,$ then the integral in question converges absolutely. Thus the Schwartz functions $f$ for which absolute convergence of the integral fails for every $x$ are precisely the Schwartz functions that are positive everywhere, or negative everywhere.